# React Redux - Pass data from state to another component to display list of results

Tags: reactjs, redux

How to pass data from Redux obtained in one component to another component.

```
let map_usersList = users.data && users.data.map((userlist => (

...
...       <ul>
              {map_usersList}
          </ul>
```

In the same search.js component, this displays the result fine.

The problem is when I have a separate component to display the list and the results:

```
import SearchResult from './Result/searchResult'
```

Here is **searchResult.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import PropTypes from 'prop-types'
import AppLink from '../../../others/link/link'


class SearchResult extends Component {

SearchResult.propTypes = {
  id: PropTypes.number.isRequired,
  username: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
}

export default SearchResult
```

I am getting the count but nothing in the data. For example, user_id is undefined.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you sure you are trying to use the right object property names? I see that you use `userlist.id` for your key. So, your users value must be something like: `{ id: 1, username: "foo" }` But, in your `SearchResult` component you use those variables like `user_id`, `user_username`. Here is a simple, working example mostly with your code.

```js
const users = [
  { id: 1, username: "foo" },
  { id: 2, username: "bar" },
  { id: 3, username: "baz" },
];

class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    let map_usersList = users && users.map(userlist => (
      <SearchResult key={userlist.id} {...userlist} />
    ));

    return <div>{map_usersList}</div>;
  }
}

class SearchResult extends React.Component {
  render() {
    let {
      id,
      username,
    } = this.props

    console.log("USER IS IS     " + id)

    return (
      <div className="noti follow_noti">
      <p>User Id: {id}, Username: {username}</p>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: That was my mistake, It works fine using the right property. Thanks much.